# How to host laravel web application in Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel

I have developed a web application using Laravel 5.8, now I want to host that to a shared web server. What will be the folder structure and exact what to configure.

1. I have created a folder named laravel and kept all the project folders into that laravel folder, except project's public folder. I kept all the files and folders of public folder into public_html folder.
2. I have configured the index.php file of public_html folder as below.

a. `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`
to,

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

b. `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`
to,

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

***** I have solved the problem myself.**

Step 1: I have found and installed laravel app into public_html folder from the cPanel

Step 2: Then I have moved everything into a folder named **laravel** except **public** folder into a new folder outside **public_html** folder

Step 3: Then I have moved everything from **public** folder into **public_html** folder

Step 4: Later I have followed the 2nd step above

Step 5: Then I have changed folder permission for **storage** folder and it works fine.

Step 6: Finally I have kept all other files and folders of the app developed in my local server into this newly installed app directories

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation

Comment: Hi Uzzwal Dhali, You should provide more details. Your hosting provider and other details. If you looking for new server You can check [A2HOSTING](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/laravel1). I have hosted my Laravel Project with same hosting provider.

Comment: Check the site at idhali.com - the site is live now. But nothing is showing when I am logging in. Do I need to configure any route? or anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel default structure always better. its depend on your hosting place.
if your hosting place support for laravel framework then use default structure automatically public word redirect to project path.
**Or** if you need to ignore Public word in your Url

- Copy all files form files put in to one folder ex:psl
- copy public folder paste in to folder directory
- change the index.php file in two place

  `require __DIR__.'/psl/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/psl/bootstrap/app.php';`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors on my deploy and then I noticed that the path is kind of wrong:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

the leading `/` changes to the root of the drive, and then the `..` are not doing anything. Removing that leading `/` on both `require __DIR__` fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

**if you can not provide a link to the web root of the shared folder!**

1. All except the Public folder to move to a higher level, such as a folder laravel - http://prntscr.com/bryvu7
   (Maybe on hosting your folder - public. not a folder public_html)
2. Change file publi_html/index.php
   line

   `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

And line

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

3. Change file laravel/server.php
   line

   `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';`

to

```
require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
```

Comment: Check the site at http://www.idhali.com - the site is live now. But nothing is showing when I am logging in. Do I need to configure any route? or anything else!